# StackView starches ButtonA when ButtonB is hidden

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I have a stack view with 2 buttons.

[image]

When ButtonA is hidden, buttonB is stretched.

[image]

I would like Button B to have the same width as it was specified. How do I set the UIStuckView appropriately.
Here is the setup I am doing right now:
 [image]

Comment: Does your stack view have any constraints?

Comment: If you just have these two buttons, then the set up is not too complex to use stack view only. An alternate would be, You can put these two buttons in a `UIView` and put fix width constraint to them.

Comment: @luda : By default StackView takes implicit size based on the content inside it. As UIButton takes its size based on title or image set (unless of course overriden by constraints) StackView will not stretch the content inside it. you must be having width constraint to stackView. If yes update your question with those info. Finally, what do u mean by when B is hidden, you are setting its frame to CGSize.zero or removing it from superView, because simply hiding button will not remove it from stackView

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could do is to setup constraints on button B

```
buttonB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Or you could put your button inside another view and then setup leading and trailing constraints between the button and outer view to make sure button doesn't exceed the desired width.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these button inside containerView's and set fix width and height for buttons so that only the ContainerViews will adjust their size while buttons will only adjust their position. Following can give you an idea of this setup,

[image]

Here `RedContainerView` has three constraints with `zero` from `left`, `top` and `bottom` to `StackView`

Similarly `GreenContainerView` has three constraints with `zero` from `right`, `top` and `bottom`

And the `A button` is `center` `vertically` and `horizontally` to `RedContainerView` with fix `width` and height as 40.

Similarly the `B button` is `center` `vertically` and `horizontally` to `GreenContainerView` with fix `width` and height as 40.

Now, when both containerView's are visible, you will get this,

[image]

And when you will set `RedViewContainer's` `isHidden` to `true`, `GreenContainerView` will adjust accordingly as below,

[image]